# Error in SQL statement when passing a parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't find the error in this SQL select command. The database is mySql. The select command works perfectly well with MS ACCESS database though:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recipesConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recipesConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT IDrecipe, title FROM recipe WHERE (title LIKE '%' + @IDTextBox1 + '%')">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above generates the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 'sauce' + '%')' at line 1
```

Comment: Try `WHERE (title LIKE CONCAT('%', @IDTextBox1, '%'))`, because `+` is _not_ string concatenation in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this without extra quotes and + .

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT IDrecipe, title 
                FROM recipe 
                WHERE title LIKE '%' @IDTextBox1 '%' ">
```

Comment: Thank you! the correct command is
SelectCommand="SELECT IDrecipe, title FROM recipe WHERE title LIKE '%' @IDTextBox1 '%' ">

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `+` operator in mysql to jam strings together; use CONCAT():

```
SelectCommand="SELECT IDrecipe, title FROM recipe WHERE (title LIKE CONCAT('%', @IDTextBox1, '%') )">
```